Question about sum check protocol O notations when applied to SAT
When reading book titled "Proofs, Arguments, and Zero-Knowledge" by Justin Thaler, i have a question about why the prover run time is as following graph show(at most), because Table 4.1 show are not as this. on page 41.


"Proofs, Arguments and ZK"book link
https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf
